# RangeSlider fills all available width in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, rangeslider

When I am trying to put some composable after `RangeSlider`, `RangeSlider` fills all width.
For example:

```kotlin
Row {
    Text(text = "Test1")
    var range by remember { mutableStateOf(-20f..20f) }
    RangeSlider(
        values = range, onValueChange = {
            range = it
        },
        colors = SliderDefaults.colors(
            thumbColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
            activeTrackColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer
        ),
        valueRange = -50f..50f
    )
    Text(text = "Test2")
}
```

In this case `Text` with `Test2` is invisible.
When I am trying to force `RangeSlider` to be with some width, second slider is out of track. Also, `Modifier.weigth()` does not work.

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210289161), fix should be available in upcoming releases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using another Layout that wraps `RangeSlider` solves the issue. Don't know why RangeSlider does not abide `Modifier.weigth()`

```
   Row {
        Text(text = "Test1")
        var range by remember { mutableStateOf(-20f..20f) }
        Row(
            modifier= Modifier.weight(1f),
            ){
            RangeSlider(
                values = range, onValueChange = {
                    range = it
                },
                valueRange = -50f..50f
            )
        }
        Text(text = "Test2")
    }
```

Comment: Weird... this composable is marked as Experimental so would be worth filing a bug on their tracker

Comment: @ptitvinou It's a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210289161), fix should be available in upcoming releases